# Where can I go to start learning what my terminal is trying to say to me

Tags: command-line

this is an example that I'm running across trying to install sublime text 2

Err:7 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F57D4F59BD3DF454

Comment: You could try copying and pasting that exact text into google

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  There is nothing in what you have posted that mentions your release of Ubuntu, and thus your question could be off-topic.

Comment: ps:  I'd use the 571 upvoted answer.  (*upvote value may have changed when you see it*)

Answer (score 3):

Generally, most of the time the messages in the terminal are pretty self explaining.

Except sometimes they are not. What I do is google for the message and pretty much every time there is a hit.

The problem you have above can be explained like that.

When you try to download a package, some mechanism has to make sure that you really got what you tried to download, and that the download is not tampered.

A way to do this is to sign a package with a cryptographic key. This is what was done with your package. In order to verify the download is correct, you need a `public key` - which is stated in the message.

You have to install the key on your machine.

For sublime it is listed on their site at:
https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/linux_repositories.html

Comment: I normally do the same though sometimes I get a hit but for another installation. For example, I'm trying to install MicroStack. it says just to wait 15-20 minutes depending on internet speed. I've been waiting an hour and I use ethernet. So what is these numbers and why am I waiting so long? I couldn't find a hit on this.

Comment: $ sudo microstack.init --auto

2019-11-15 17:13:47,003 - microstack_init - INFO - Setting up ipv4 forwarding...
2019-11-15 17:13:47,386 - microstack_init - INFO - Waiting for RabbitMQ to start ...
Waiting for 10.20.20.1:5672
2019-11-15 17:13:47,411 - microstack_init - INFO - RabbitMQ started!
2019-11-15 17:13:47,412 - microstack_init - INFO - Configuring RabbitMQ ...
2019-11-15 17:13:54,781 - microstack_init - INFO - RabbitMQ Configured!
2019-11-15 17:13:55,002 - microstack_init - INFO - Waiting for MySQL server to start ...
Waiting for 10.20.20.1:3306

Comment: @Nobody If you paste that text into your Question and on newlines above and below it put three backticks (to the left of 1 on a US keyboard) the formatting will make look MUCH more understandable.

Comment: Which one is a backtick a` or a~.....I'm thinking the first.